# Build blocks and isolate characters OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ocr

I have been searching for an answer for a while to this question but cannot find anything useful.

I am trying to read machine readable zone with a camera. I need to extract characters one by one from machine readable zone and feed to OCR. I tried to threshold image, to find contours, extract characters one by one but while it is on live camera find contours miss some characters and I get results not as I expected.

While machine readable zone is known size, form, is there a proper method to build blocks for each character and extract them?

**UPDATE CODE**

```
rect = []
blur = cv2.medianBlur(roi_gray,3) #roi_gray is aligned horizontally MRZ zone
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:90]
minH = 20
minW = 20
for ctr in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(ctr) < 1000:
        xyc,wh,a = cv2.minAreaRect(ctr)
        w,h = wh
        x,y = xyc
        if h >= minH or w >= minW:
            rect.append(cv2.boundingRect(cv2.approxPolyDP(ctr,3,True)))
```

rect is containing collected contours but problem is that after thresholding as example character N is splitting into two contours, or it was not found by findContours so letter is missing in finally output.

**Video**

I have found video there seems author build blocks for each character but unfortunately author does not provide any additional information about method or code. [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CaBmIKTO6Y)

Comment: it would be much easier for us to help you, if you've provided us with at least one image of the situation you're describing.

Comment: i have provided a video link

Comment: Yes but that's a working software. It would be easier to help you if you've shown us where exactly you have problems. Like, for example, image after thresholding and during contours finding. Your biggest enemy here is scale and perspective shifts - the video demonstrates an algorithms that is fairly robust to minor angle shifts.

Comment: Yes, you are right after thresholding I'm experiencing scale problems when characters disappear, as example character N after thresholding, findContour is finding as two contours not one contour. I am sorry I am not able to upload pictures right now I will do it later.

Comment: I don't know am I right but if I am able to find 4 characters top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right so I could get real dimensions of MRZ zone? When to calculate distance between characters and when I will be able to get real size and location of character? I am sorry I could be wrong I am newbie with CV I am just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me that ID text of interest area has an aspect ratio, maybe the block means that text area. Having an aspect ration (-+ an error) it may be a possibility to remove other text areas. In OpenCV 3 there is a [detector for text](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html).
More, I suppose the area detected is tracked, at least it seems so in the video.

IMHO that app is doing a blur, then a binarization then a erode-dilate to detect text lines. So, after a wrap correction (or maybe even a little perspective correction), with a vertical projection you can detect the character width, so you can detect each character and feed it to the OCR.

---

According to the comment, I add the info for the character area. I would do an opening operation for filling white spaces inside the letters, or linking the contours. Then, by simply vertical sum the pixels values, you'll get a vertical projection. now you have some minimums between the characters. Using those minimums you can get a character width by averaging the distances between them.

What you can also do is not processing on each frame this width, but getting a width that vary not too much over consecutive frames. You can achieve this by doing an average over widths in the last 5 frames (using a queue).

Try it and come back with some results, like this we will be able to help you more.

There is an [OpenCV forum](http://answers.opencv.org/), too, there you'll probably find more informations

Comment: I am already detecting text of interest extract it, doing perspective correction and I am getting 3 MRZ lines of text, could you explain more about vertical projection? Because my main problem that findContours is missing letters or their structure, like I said before detecting character N like two contours.